# How can I rewrite a python 2D vector in C#?

Tags: python, c#, c#-2.0

The following is a 2D array of vectors in Python:

```
 neighbor =  [[1, 3, 0, 0], [2, 4, 0, 1], [2, 5, 1, 2],
             [4, 6, 3, 0], [5, 7, 3, 1], [5, 8, 4, 2],
             [7, 6, 6, 3], [8, 7, 6, 4], [8, 8, 7, 5]];
```

How can I rewrite this into C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
int[,] neighbor = new int[,] {{1, 3, 0, 0}, {2, 4, 0, 1}, {2, 5, 1, 2},
                              {4, 6, 3, 0}, {5, 7, 3, 1}, {5, 8, 4, 2},
                              {7, 6, 6, 3}, {8, 7, 6, 4}, {8, 8, 7, 5}};
```

Or like this

```
int[,] neighbor = {{1, 3, 0, 0}, {2, 4, 0, 1}, {2, 5, 1, 2},
                   {4, 6, 3, 0}, {5, 7, 3, 1}, {5, 8, 4, 2},
                   {7, 6, 6, 3}, {8, 7, 6, 4}, {8, 8, 7, 5}};
```

Microsoft article for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays